# Evenly select N elems from array

Tags: algorithm

I need to **evenly** select *n* elements from an array. I guess the best way to explain is by example.

say I have:

array [0,1,2,3,4] and I need to select 3 numbers.. 0,2,4.

of course, if the array length <= *n*, I just need to return the whole array.

I'm pretty sure there's a defined algorithm for this, been trying to search, and I took a look at *Introduction to algorithms* but couldn't find anything that met my needs (probably overlooked it)

The problem I'm having is that I can't figure out a way to scale this up to any array [ p..q ], selecting N evenly elements.

note: I can't just select the even elements from the example above..

A couple other examples;

array[0,1,2,3,4,5,6], 3 elements ; I need to get 0,3,6
array[0,1,2,3,4,5],   3 elements ; I need to get 0, either 2 or 3, and 5

EDIT:

more examples:
array [0,1,2], 2 elems : 0,2
array [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 5 elems : 0,2, either 3 or 4,  5,7

and yes, I'd like to include first and last elements always.

EDIT 2:

what I was thinking was something like .. first + last element, then work my way up using the median value. Though I got stuck/confused when trying to do so.

I'll take a look at the algo you're posting. thanks!

EDIT 3:

Here's a souped up version of *incrediman* solution with PHP. Works with associative arrays as well, while retaining the keys.

```
<?php

/**
 * Selects $x elements (evenly distributed across $set) from $set
 *
 * @param $set array : array set to select from
 * @param $x int     : number of elements to select. positive integer
 *
 * @return array|bool : selected set, bool false on failure
 */
///FIXME when $x = 1 .. return median .. right now throws a warning, division by zero

function select ($set, $x) {
    //check params
    if (!is_array($set) || !is_int($x) || $x < 1)
        return false;

    $n = count($set);

    if ($n <= $x)
        return $set;

    $selected = array ();
    $step     = ($n - 1) / ($x - 1);
    $keys     = array_keys  ($set);
    $values   = array_values($set);

    for ($i=0; $i<$x; $i++) {
        $selected[$keys[round($step*$i)]] = $values[round($step*$i)];
    }

    return $selected;
}

?>
```

You can probably implement an [Iterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php) but I don't need to take it that far.

Comment: What numbers do you need to select? Be more specific about your pattern.

Comment: I think you need some more examples, cause I still don't understand what you're trying to do. What about longer arrays and a different number of elements to select?

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, the OP wants to selects a number of array elements whose indices follow some regular pattern.  I think Rex Kerr's answer might better explain what is being asked here.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Pseudo-code:

```
function Algorithm(int N,array A)
    float step=(A.size-1)/(N-1)       //set step size

    array R                           //declare return array

    for (int i=0, i<N, i++)
        R.push(A[round(step*i)])  //push each element of a position which is a
                                      //multiple of step to R

    return R
```

Probably the easiest mistake to make here would be to cast `step` as an integer or round it at the beginning. However, in order to make sure that the correct elements are pulled, you must declare `step` as a floating point number, and **round *multiples of `step`*** as you are iterating through the array.

Tested example here in php:

```
<?

    function Algorithm($N,$A){
        
        $step=(sizeof($A)-1)/($N-1);
        for ($i=0;$i<$N;$i++)
            echo $A[round($step*$i)]." ";
        echo "\n";
    }
    
    //some of your test cases:
    Algorithm(3,array(1,2,3));
    Algorithm(5,array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7));
    Algorithm(2,array(0,1,2));
    Algorithm(3,array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6));
?>

Outputs:
1 2 3 
0 2 4 5 7 
0 2 
0 3 6
```

(you can see your test cases in action and try new ones here: http://codepad.org/2eZp98eD)

Comment: Where is "step" being used? I'm only seeing its declaration.

Comment: @nin,- typo. Should make more sense now.

Comment: damn dude, checked out the codepad link, according to input => output, exactly what I was looking for. I'll look into the function tomorrow and tune it up a bit, since now it's way too late into the night. cheers mate!

Comment: yo, added my own implementation if you're interested to take a look ;)

Answer (score 3):

Let `n+1` be the number of elements you want, already bounded to the length of the array.

Then you want elements at indices `0/n`, `1/n`, ..., `n/n` of the way to the end of the array.

Let `m+1` be the length of the array.  Then your indices are `round(m*i/n)` (with the division done with floating point).

Comment: This is incorrect. With a `0`-indexed array of length `m`, the last index should be `m-1` not `m`, so the indices should be `round((m-1)*i/n)` (division in floating point, as stated).

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you add a structured pseudo-code.. I think you might be on the right track but I'm not following you 100%.

Comment: @clueless: Whoops.  Fixed to `m+1` as the length of the array.  That's what I was trying to type (as with the `n+1`).

Answer (score 1):

Your step size is (ArraySize-1)/(N-1).
Just add the step size to a floating point accumulator, and round off the accumulator to get the array index.  Repeat until accumulator > array size.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to include both the first and last elements in your list.

If you want to pull X items from your list of N items, your step size will be (N-1)/(X-1).  Just round however you want as you pull out each one.

Answer (score 1):

Based on **Rex's** answer!

```js
// Handles all the edge cases.
function select(array, selectionCount) {
    let iterationCount = array.length - 1;         // Number of iterations
    let expectedToBeSelected = selectionCount - 1; // Number of elements to be selected
    let resultsArray = [];                         // Result Array
    
    if (selectionCount < 1 || selectionCount > array.length) {
        console.log("Invalid selection count!");
        return resultsArray;
    }

    for (let i in array) {
        if (selectionCount == 1) {
            resultsArray.push(array[i]);
            break;
        }
        let selectedSoFar = Math.round(iterationCount * i / expectedToBeSelected);
        if (selectedSoFar < array.length) {
            resultsArray.push(array[selectedSoFar]);
        } else {
            break; // If selectedSoFar is greater than the length then do not proceed further.
        }
    }

    return resultsArray;
}
```