# Choose N evenly spaced elements from a table in Lua

Tags: math, lua

I am trying to write a program that will evenly pick N numbers from a given array of integers

My attempt is a Lua implementation based off this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2451363

I changed `local step = (tableLen-1)/(n-1)` to `local step = (tableLen-2)/(n-1)`
because in Lua tables start at 1 (it also did not work before that change). I am having weird results. For example when I try to choose 3 numbers from the array it will pick 27 when the array's highest member is 20. I think the problem might lie in the `tableLen-2` or the index I am starting the for loop at (0 vs 1).

Here is my code

```
myTable = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20}

local tableLen = table.getn(myTable) --20

local n = 3

print("choosing " .. n .. " numbers")

local step = (tableLen-2)/(n-1)

local count = 0

for i=0,n,1 do
    count = count + 1
    local wantedIndex = math.floor((step * i) + 0.5)
    print("wanted index " .. wantedIndex)
    if wantedIndex > tableLen then
        print("out of bounds!")
    end
end

local worked = n == count
print("did it match? " .. tostring(worked) .. " count " .. tostring(count))
```

Here is the output for n=3

```
choosing 3 numbers
wanted index 0
wanted index 9
wanted index 18
wanted index 27
out of bounds!
did it match? false count 4
```

Here is n=15

```
wanted index 0
wanted index 1
wanted index 3
wanted index 4
wanted index 5
wanted index 6
wanted index 8
wanted index 9
wanted index 10
wanted index 12
wanted index 13
wanted index 14
wanted index 15
wanted index 17
wanted index 18
wanted index 19
did it match? false count 16
```

Comment: What does "evenly" mean? Do you want the first picked number to be the first item of the given table and the last, the last, or should there be a gap before the first and after the last chosen item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you'ce confusing step with how many items are retrieved.  They *can be* the same value, if you desire, but don't have to be.

```
#! /usr/bin/env lua

local myTable = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20}

local begin = 5
local items = 4
local step = 3

local text = 'Beginning at index %d, and printing %d items, every %d steps:\n'
print( string.format( text,  begin,  items,  step ) )

for i=begin,  #myTable,  step do
    print( string.format( 'index %2d   value: %2d',  i,  myTable[i] ) )

    items = items -1
    if items == 0 then break end  --  break out of loop once amount of items have been retrieved
end
```

Beginning at index 5, and printing 4 items, every 3 steps:

`index  5   value:  5`
`index  8   value:  8`
`index 11   value: 11`
`index 14   value: 14`

---

**Edit:**

Oh, you'll only get evenly spaced items if your list length is evenly divisible by n.  So 20 elements: 1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 20.  Smaller steps will have to break out of the loop, or they might give one more than expected, because `math.floor()` drops the fraction that would otherwise add up to that last full digit.

```
#! /usr/bin/env lua

local myTable = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20}

local n = 6

for i=1,  #myTable,  math.floor( #myTable /n ) do
    print( string.format( 'index %2d   value: %2d',  i,  myTable[i] ) )
    n = n -1
    if n == 0 then break end
end
```

`index  1   value:  1`
`index  4   value:  4`
`index  7   value:  7`
`index 10   value: 10`
`index 13   value: 13`
`index 16   value: 16`

---

**Edit:**

centers values, by splitting difference of the remainder.

```
local myTable = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20}

local n = 4
local step = math.floor( #myTable /n )
begin = math.floor( math.max( 1,  ( #myTable -((n -1) *step) +1 ) /2 ) )

for i=begin,  #myTable,  step do
    print( string.format( 'index %2d   value: %2d',  i,  myTable[i] ) )
    n = n -1
    if n == 0 then break end
end
```

`index  3   value:  3`
`index  8   value:  8`
`index 13   value: 13`
`index 18   value: 18`

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the step should be calculated based off the size of the array and the amount of numbers you want evenly picked from the array. Not explicitly set to be every N numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want something like this?

```lua
local function evenly(number, items)
    local space = math.floor((#items-1) / (number-1))
    for i=1,#items,space do
        print(items[i])
    end
end

evenly(5, {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20})
```